# Display 2nd DropDownList when selecting specific value from 1st DropDownList?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a regular webform with two `DropDownLists`: DropDown1 & Dropdown2. Neither are data-bound and are populated manually with the `asp:ListItem` tag.

DropDown1 has two values: **To Buy** and **Bought**. When I select the listitem **Bought** I would like to display Dropdown2 using `javascript` (no server-side code).
Since I would also like to hide it using `display:none`, I was considering wrapping the Dropdown2 within a `DIV`. And with the 1st `DropDownList` hide/display the Dropdown2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no jQuery guru, so I'm sure there's a more succinct way of doing this, but the following works...

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDown1">
    <asp:ListItem Text="To Buy" Value="ToBuy" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Bought" Value="Bought" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<br/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDown2" style="display: none;">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 1" Value="val1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 2" Value="val2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 3" Value="val3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Value 4" Value="val4" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var dd1 = $get('<%= DropDown1.ClientID %>');
        var dd2 = $get('<%= DropDown2.ClientID %>');

        $(dd1).change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'Bought')
                $(dd2).show();
            else
                $(dd2).hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way.

My dropdown:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Status" runat="server" onchange="HideDropDown(this);">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Plan" Value="Plan" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Launched" Value="Launched"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideDropDown(e) {
        var SelectedValue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=DropDownListPlanStatus.ClientID%>");

        if ((SelectedValue) == "Launched") {
            ddl.style.display = "none";  //hide dropdown
            alert(SelectedValue);
        }
        else {
            ddl.style.display = "block"; //display dropdown
            alert(SelectedValue);
        }
    } 
</script>
```